# <verbal noun> of <noun> - articles before the second noun are omitted

Tags: articles

It seems that, when a verbal noun is followed by "of-noun" phrase,
the second noun uses zero-articles.

Is my understanding correct?

For example:

> Denial of **human rights**
>
> Rejection of
> **payment order**

Comment: I don't think this is a fixed rule. The first one presumably refers to human rights in general, so an article isn't needed. The second is OK if you are referring to a general idea, but if you mean a particular payment order you would need an article.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you for your comment. Oh OK.  When you say a [kind/type/sort/] of something, the articles are dropped. For some reason, I thought that the same principle would apply here.